# Classe DAO gravando em múltiplas tabelas

Tags: banco-de-dados, padrão-dao

Possuo um objeto model `Mensagem` que possui os atributos `Tipo` e `Descricao`, as informações deste objeto deve ser gravado em um banco de dados, para isso criei uma classe DAO responsável pro inseri-la no banco porem dependendo do valor do atributo `Tipo` a `Mensagem` deverá ser gravado em uma outra tabela, como adequar esta multiplicidade de opções de gravação em BD em uma classe DAO?

Comment: Mande um modelo do que vc já fez?
Qual linguagem de programação que vc está usando?
e qual estrutura do seu banco de dados? pois de outra forma não dá pra saber qual seria essa "outra tabela" que vc que inserir o dado!